# Screensaver only on primary screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, screensaver

I'm trying to set a screensaver only on primary screen. Is it possible?

I know, that I can disable screensaver on specified monitors using screensaver settings->display settings, but I'm looking for an option, to set "Enabled only on primary screen".

Maybe it is possible via registry or gpedit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually dependent on the screen-saver itself, if it was programmed
with this possibility. If it was, this is normally set in its Settings page.

You could also look for some configuration settings on your display adapter,
as some adapters do have that option.

There are products that can force this, but they are usually commercial.
One I know of is
[Actual Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/articles/detail.php?ID=1392),
and another might be [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/),
but I don't believe that this is worth the cost.

Comment: Thanks, information about that it is dependent on the screen saver helps me a lot.